# How to place components in GridBaglayout from top left and then vertically?

Tags: java, swing, location, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to place my buttons like the ones in PIC 2, but they end up being placed like the ones in PIC 1 .(PIC 2 is edited in paint). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? How do I place then from top left and then the next one under that one and so on?

PICS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7f8Z.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public class TestTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
JButton b9 = new JButton("9");



public static void main(String[] args){

    new TestTwo();

}

public TestTwo(){

    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    p1.setLayout(gbl);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 0;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

    p1.add(b1, gbc);

    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(b2, gbc);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // do nothing

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more instructions, examples, etc., on how to use GBL. This works for me, hope it helps!

```
public TestTwo() {
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout(gbl);
    p1.setLayout(gbl);

    gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
            GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(
                  0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
    add(p1, gbc); //add p1 in a GBL too, so it ends up in the northwest corner

    p1.add(b1, gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(b2, gbc);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```